# No kernel option buttons on jupyter-lab

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, conda, jupyter-lab

I just set up my new computer and have an issue with Jupyter-lab. I can't find the "*interrupt kernel*", "*restart kernel*" and "*restart kernel and run all buttons** like in the image below:

[image: Missing buttons]

My window currently looks like:

[image: Current window]

I installed miniconda following the instructions (version *4.12.0*). I created a conda environment, installed my required packages and jupyter (version *1.0.0*) as well as jupyterlab (version *3.4.4*) with the latest version for all of them.
I also added my virtual environment as a kernel using ipykernel.

I am on Windows 10, 64 bits.

Thanks for your help

The output of `conda list`:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anyio                     3.5.0           py310haa95532_0
appdirs                   1.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0          py310h2bbff1b_0
asttokens                 2.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
attrs                     21.4.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
audioread                 2.1.9           py310h5588dad_3    conda-forge
babel                     2.9.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
beautifulsoup4            4.11.1          py310haa95532_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
bottleneck                1.3.5           py310h9128911_0
brotli                    1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py310h2bbff1b_1002
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2022.6.15            h5b45459_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2022.6.15       py310h5588dad_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.15.1          py310h2bbff1b_0
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
colorama                  0.4.5           py310haa95532_0
cryptography              37.0.1          py310h21b164f_0
cudatoolkit               11.6.0              hc0ea762_10    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
debugpy                   1.5.1           py310hd77b12b_0
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
easydict                  1.9                        py_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.4             py310haa95532_0
executing                 0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype                  2.10.4               hd328e21_0
glib                      2.69.1               h5dc1a3c_1
gst-plugins-base          1.18.5               h9e645db_0
gstreamer                 1.18.5               hd78058f_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3
idna                      3.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0
importlib-metadata        4.11.4          py310h5588dad_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          haa95532_3556
ipykernel                 6.9.1           py310haa95532_0
ipython                   8.4.0           py310haa95532_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
ipywidgets                7.6.5              pyhd3eb1b0_1
jedi                      0.18.1          py310haa95532_1
jinja2                    3.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
joblib                    1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jpeg                      9e                   h2bbff1b_0
json5                     0.9.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jsonschema                4.4.0           py310haa95532_0
jupyter                   1.0.0           py310haa95532_8
jupyter_client            7.2.2           py310haa95532_0
jupyter_console           6.4.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_core              4.10.0          py310haa95532_0
jupyter_server            1.18.1          py310haa95532_0
jupyterlab                3.4.4           py310haa95532_0
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
jupyterlab_server         2.12.0          py310haa95532_0
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
kiwisolver                1.4.2           py310hd77b12b_0
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
libclang                  12.0.0          default_h627e005_2
libffi                    3.4.2                hd77b12b_4
libflac                   1.3.4                h0e60522_0    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.16                 h2bbff1b_2
libogg                    1.3.5                h2bbff1b_1
libopus                   1.3.1                h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
librosa                   0.9.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
libsndfile                1.0.31               h0e60522_1    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h62dcd97_0
libtiff                   4.2.0                he0120a3_1
libuv                     1.40.0               he774522_0
libvorbis                 1.3.7                he774522_0
libwebp                   1.2.2                h2bbff1b_0
libxml2                   2.9.14               h0ad7f3c_0
libxslt                   1.1.35               h2bbff1b_0
llvmlite                  0.38.0          py310h23ce68f_0
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h2bbff1b_1
markupsafe                2.1.1           py310h2bbff1b_0
matplotlib                3.5.1           py310haa95532_1
matplotlib-base           3.5.1           py310hd77b12b_1
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_2
mistune                   0.8.4           py310h2bbff1b_1000
mkl                       2021.4.0           haa95532_640
mkl-service               2.4.0           py310h2bbff1b_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.1           py310ha0764ea_0
mkl_random                1.2.2           py310h4ed8f06_0
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0
nbclassic                 0.3.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nbclient                  0.5.13          py310haa95532_0
nbconvert                 6.4.4           py310haa95532_0
nbformat                  5.3.0           py310haa95532_0
nest-asyncio              1.5.5           py310haa95532_0
notebook                  6.4.12          py310haa95532_0
numba                     0.55.1          py310h4ed8f06_0
numexpr                   2.8.3           py310hb57aa6b_0
numpy                     1.21.5          py310h6d2d95c_3
numpy-base                1.21.5          py310h206c741_3
openssl                   1.1.1q               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandas                    1.4.3           py310hd77b12b_0
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pcre                      8.45                 hd77b12b_0
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    9.2.0           py310hdc2b20a_1
pip                       22.1.2          py310haa95532_0
ply                       3.11            py310haa95532_0
pooch                     1.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
prettytable               3.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.14.1          py310haa95532_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.20             pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt_toolkit            3.0.20               hd3eb1b0_0
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygments                  2.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyopenssl                 22.0.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyparsing                 3.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyqt                      5.15.7          py310hd77b12b_0
pyqt5-sip                 12.11.0         py310hd77b12b_0
pyrsistent                0.18.0          py310h2bbff1b_0
pysocks                   1.7.1           py310haa95532_0
pysoundfile               0.10.3.post1       pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
python                    3.10.4               hbb2ffb3_0
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-fastjsonschema     2.15.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
python_abi                3.10                    2_cp310    conda-forge
pytorch                   1.12.1          py3.10_cuda11.6_cudnn8_0    pytorch
pytorch-mutex             1.0                        cuda    pytorch
pytz                      2022.1          py310haa95532_0
pywin32                   302             py310h2bbff1b_2
pywinpty                  2.0.2           py310h5da7b33_0
pyyaml                    6.0             py310h2bbff1b_0
pyzmq                     23.2.0          py310hd77b12b_0
qt-main                   5.15.2               he8e5bd7_4
qt-webengine              5.15.9               hb9a9bb5_4
qtconsole                 5.3.1           py310haa95532_1
qtpy                      2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtwebkit                  5.212                h3ad3cdb_4
requests                  2.28.1          py310haa95532_0
resampy                   0.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
scikit-learn              1.1.1           py310hd77b12b_0
scipy                     1.7.3           py310h6d2d95c_0
seaborn                   0.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
setuptools                61.2.0          py310haa95532_0
sip                       6.6.2           py310hd77b12b_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
sniffio                   1.2.0           py310haa95532_1
soupsieve                 2.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sqlite                    3.39.0               h2bbff1b_0
stack_data                0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tbb                       2021.5.0             h59b6b97_0
terminado                 0.13.1          py310haa95532_0
testpath                  0.6.0           py310haa95532_0
threadpoolctl             2.2.0              pyh0d69192_0
tk                        8.6.12               h2bbff1b_0
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
torchaudio                0.12.1              py310_cu116    pytorch
torchvision               0.13.1              py310_cu116    pytorch
tornado                   6.1             py310h2bbff1b_0
tqdm                      4.64.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
typing-extensions         4.3.0           py310haa95532_0
typing_extensions         4.3.0           py310haa95532_0
tzdata                    2022a                hda174b7_0
urllib3                   1.26.11         py310haa95532_0
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
webencodings              0.5.1           py310haa95532_1
websocket-client          0.58.0          py310haa95532_4
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.2           py310haa95532_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0           py310haa95532_0
wincertstore              0.2             py310haa95532_2
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
xz                        5.2.5                h8cc25b3_1
yaml                      0.2.5                he774522_0
zeromq                    4.3.4                hd77b12b_0
zipp                      3.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.12               h8cc25b3_2
zstd                      1.5.2                h19a0ad4_0
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your browser window what it actually looks like? Can you include the output of `conda list` from your env?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache and done a hard refresh on the page? Given it is a reported bug (see following), it may not help but worth trying that as a starting point always. -- That issue is reported [here as 'empty menu bar jupyterlab=3.4.4'](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/12862). You may want to report your experience, particular browser there. In that case, the workaround was to go back to 3.4.3 or use Chrome (I think). Are you using an old system / old browser like in that report?